# Which GPU model/brand is optimal for Neural Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gpu

This is not an unreasonable question. Nvidia and ATI architectures differ, enough so that for certain tasks (such as bitcoin mining) ATI is vastly better than Nvidia.

The same could be true for Neural Network related processing. I have attempted to find comparisons of the 2 GPU brands in such a context but failed to do so.

My expectation is that the most important thing for Neural Network processing in a GPU is the number of cores. Would that be correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost all ML software that uses GPU works (best) with CUDA, thus Nvidia's GPUs are preferable.

Take a look at [this discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/2vgs3g/best_langenvironment_to_take_advantage_of/). And, there's an article about [which GPU to get for deep learning](https://timdettmers.wordpress.com/2014/08/14/which-gpu-for-deep-learning/) (modern neural networks). Relevant quote:

> **So what kind of GPU should I get? NVIDIA or AMD?**
>
> NVIDIA’s standard libraries made it very easy to establish the first deep learning libraries in CUDA, while there were no such powerful standard libraries for AMD’s OpenCL. Right now, there are just no good deep learning libraries for AMD cards – so NVIDIA it is. Even if some OpenCL libraries would be available in the future I would stick with NVIDIA: The thing is that the GPU computing or GPGPU community is very large for CUDA and rather small for OpenCL. Thus in the CUDA community good open source solutions and solid advice for your programming is readily available.

The reason NVIDIA rocks is that they invested a lot of effort into support of scientific computing (see [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuDNN), for example. This means they acknowledge the field and try to move towards these applications).

**So, NVIDIA has lots of GPUs. Which one should you get?**

Short answer, based on the article cited above (I strongly suggest to read it!): GTX 980.

Actually, number of cores is not that significant. GPUs don't have tons of memory, so communication with host (your RAM) is inevitable. So what matters is amount of on-board memory (so that you can load and process more), and bandwidth (so you don't spend a lot of time waiting).